# How can I remove first 10s of data of a time series

Tags: r

So I have GPS tracking data that looks like this

```
     timestamp             individual
1    02/12/2020 03:22:10   A
2    02/12/2020 03:22:11   A
3    02/12/2020 03:22:12   A
4    02/12/2020 03:43:40   A
5    02/12/2020 03:43:41   A
6    02/12/2020 03:43:43   A
7    02/12/2020 03:43:45   A
8    02/12/2020 03:43:47   A
9    02/12/2020 03:43:48   A
10   02/12/2020 03:43:50   A
11   02/12/2020 03:43:52   A
12   02/12/2020 03:43:53   A
```

It works with a tracker that sends positions every 1-3 seconds and timestamps that are far apart from each other (>10 seconds difference) indicate a new series of high frequency data (e.g., line 3 to 4). I want to remove the first 10 seconds of each time series (in this case, lines 4 to 10), including the first data point of that series, but keep the points after (11 and 12). How can I do this?

The expected output would look like this:

```
     timestamp             individual
11   02/12/2020 03:43:52   A
12   02/12/2020 03:43:53   A
```

Comment: Please provide more data.

Comment: I added some more time data if that is what you are referring to

Comment: Please also add the expected output

Comment: I added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


dat %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = parse_date_time(timestamp, orders = "dmy HMS"),
         group = 1 + cumsum(timestamp - lag(timestamp, default = first(timestamp)) > 10)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(timestamp - first(timestamp) > 10) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   timestamp           individual
#>   <dttm>              <chr>     
#> 1 2020-12-02 03:43:52 A         
#> 2 2020-12-02 03:43:53 A
```

sample data

```
dat <- structure(list(timestamp = c("02/12/2020 03:22:10", "02/12/2020 03:22:11", 
                                    "02/12/2020 03:22:12", "02/12/2020 03:43:40", "02/12/2020 03:43:41", 
                                    "02/12/2020 03:43:43", "02/12/2020 03:43:45", "02/12/2020 03:43:47", 
                                    "02/12/2020 03:43:48", "02/12/2020 03:43:50", "02/12/2020 03:43:52", 
                                    "02/12/2020 03:43:53"), 
                      individual = rep("A", 12)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                     "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))

dat
#>              timestamp individual
#> 1  02/12/2020 03:22:10          A
#> 2  02/12/2020 03:22:11          A
#> 3  02/12/2020 03:22:12          A
#> 4  02/12/2020 03:43:40          A
#> 5  02/12/2020 03:43:41          A
#> 6  02/12/2020 03:43:43          A
#> 7  02/12/2020 03:43:45          A
#> 8  02/12/2020 03:43:47          A
#> 9  02/12/2020 03:43:48          A
#> 10 02/12/2020 03:43:50          A
#> 11 02/12/2020 03:43:52          A
#> 12 02/12/2020 03:43:53          A
```